# How to bundle an openframeworks application in xcode (relative resource linking?)

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

An trying to get openframeworks to build me my application so that i can open it from anywhere and it will load the needed images from within the apps Resources folder.

I believe this is relative linking?

I have done it before, on an older xcode and oF 61.

To do this i dragged the needed images into the project file on the left and added it to the executable target, with in a 'build phase' -> 'copy files'.

Been trying all sorts of methods, ofSetDataPathRoot() which solved the problem last time isnt working for me this time.

Any ideas/help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What version of xcode are you using now? Also, what OF version?

Answer (score 9):

First you need to tell xCode to copy your /bin/data directory into your application bundle by adding a build phase:

```
1. Click on your project in the Project Navigator
2. Select "Build Phases"
3. Toggle open the "Run Script" section and paste in the following:
cp -r bin/data "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Contents/Resources";
```

Then tell your app where to find the data folder relative to itself within the bundle.

Inside the setup method of your oF app:

```
ofSetDataPathRoot("../Resources/data/");
```

Answer (score 0):

`ofSetDataPathRoot()` *should* solve this problem. Perhaps you are setting the replacement root path incorrectly?

Try calling ofToDataPath() yourself on a string path and print out the result, then use Terminal and `cd` inside the .app bundle to check if the path sounds correct. Paths are expressed relative to the location of the actual executable inside the .app bundle, so if the executable is at `myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp` and the data files are at `myApp.app/Contents/Resources` then `ofToDataPath( "texture.png" )` should return something like `../Resources/texture.png`.

You can double-check the current working directory (`myApp.app/Contents/MacOS` in my example) by calling `getcwd()`, open up a terminal and type `man getcwd` for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

oF now sets data path root *and* does internal calls to `ofToDataPath()` by default. What version are you using?

Have you looked inside the product's package contents to make sure your resources are getting copies in the proper build phase?